# Which version of .NET Framework will be required for project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-framework-version

I have two projects in my solution, e.g. Project1 and Project2. Project1 targets .NET Framework 2.0, and Project2 targets .NET Framework 3.5. Project1 has no references to Project2, the purpose of Project2 is to use the .exe file it generates in post-build of Project1. However, when I try to run Project1.exe on a machine with .NET Framework 2.0 it says that it needs .NET 3.5 to run. Is is because Project2 is in the same solution as Project1? If it is, are there any ways of resolving this apart form changing the target framework for Project2? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your project1 uses exe build in project2 which is targeted to .net 3.5 its simple that 3.5 is needed

if You want to change target for Project2 check this link:
[Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)

Comment: Well, Project1.exe does not use Project2.exe, it is used only in post-build events. There are no references from Project1 to Project2. Does it still affect the framework version needed by Project1?

Comment: Is used so app/system whatever is running it. App targeted for 3.5 can't be run without .net 3.5.  You can change target of project2 and recompile it.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. Still, only Project1.exe is deployed, and as long as it doesn't have any references to assemblies which target a higher framework version, I suppose it should successfully run with .net 2.0.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but maybe if some post-build event uses P2 there is some references which we can't see at first

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using inside project1 a library which needs .net 3.5?